# instrumentTest folder for Android unit testing in IntelliJ

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I can't seem to be getting my gradle project to recognize instrumentTest as the testing folder. As a result, the java subfolder is not green and I can't create any tests out of it. I have tried setting the sourceSet in the build.gradle file with no luck.

```
sourceSets {
    instrumentTest.setRoot("src/instrumentTest")
}
```

I also tried renaming instrumentTest to androidTest, but again it is not recognized as the testing folder. My file structure is set up like this:

```
- AppModule
    * src
        - instrumentTest
        - main
```

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to upgrade my IntelliJ version from 13.0.3 to 13.1.3. There must be some kind of bug with IntelliJ 13.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

It should be **androidTest**, not **instrumentTest**. Did you put a **java** folder inside? This structure works for me, without needing a `setRoot` statement in my build folder:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing androidTest instead of instrumentTest as some other posts have said that is the new Android standard. Still no luck with that though, it just treats java like a normal directory.

Comment: @NickThoma Did you sync your Gradle config after that change?

Comment: Yeah I resynced gradle and rebuilt the project before trying to create the java subdirectory. The only way to make it green is to go into project structure and manually set androidTest as a test directory, but that really doesn't do much good as it doesn't generate the manifest needed to actually run tests out of that directory.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: @NickThoma You say you synced *before* creating? Try syncing *afterwards*. You probably did, but just checking. Also, what version of the gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Yeah tried both. I'm using IntelliJ 13.0.3 and Gradle 1.10.

Comment: Ok so I just created a new project to test this feature on and instrumentTest worked, while androidTest did not. I still am not sure why this doesn't work on my current project.

Comment: If you're running IntelliJ 13 and not Android Studio, then there's a good chance that this has been fixed in recent versions of Android Studio, but the change hasn't been picked up in IntelliJ yet since they don't update as frequently and are running an older version of the Android plugin.